# SQL Server generate script for views and how to decide order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I am generating the script for views using SQL Server built-in feature (`Task -> Generate script`). I am creating separate file for each object (of view). I have say around 400 files (containing SQL script of all views) to be executed on another database and to do that automatically I have created BAT file which takes care of that.

There are views which are dependent on other views and due to that many views failed to execute. Is there any way by which we can set order of execution and get rid off the failure ?

Any pointers would be a great help.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Thanks

Jony

Comment: "View dependencies" menu would be helpful for you. It show on right click the view object in Object Explore.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630261%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: yes, but the point is I am trying to make things automatic. If I used the option you suggested then I need to go and check dependency for all 400 views. If tomorrow 100 more views created then it will be time-consuming activity. Moreover, I have scripts(of views) and code (to execute automatically) with me. Can we do some tweak by which we can achieve order of execution ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this query? You can execute the create scripts in order to "gen" (generation).

```
DECLARE @cnt int = 0, @index int;
DECLARE @viewNames table (number int, name varchar(max))
DECLARE @viewGen table (id uniqueidentifier, gen int, name varchar(max), parentId uniqueidentifier)

INSERT INTO @viewNames
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_Id), name FROM sys.views


SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) FROM @viewNames
SET @index = @cnt;
WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @viewGen) < @cnt)
BEGIN
 DECLARE @viewName varchar(200)
 SELECT @viewName = name FROM @viewNames WHERE number = @index;

 DECLARE @depCnt int = 0;
 SELECT @depCnt = COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.' + @viewName, 'OBJECT')
 IF (@depCnt = 0)
 BEGIN
  INSERT INTO @viewGen SELECT NEWID(), 0, name, null FROM @viewNames WHERE number = @index;
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
  IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.' + @viewName, 'OBJECT') AS r INNER JOIN @viewGen AS v ON r.referencing_entity_name = v.name)
  BEGIN 
   DECLARE @parentId uniqueidentifier = NEWID();
   INSERT INTO @viewGen SELECT @parentId, 0, name, null FROM @viewNames WHERE number = @index;

   UPDATE v
   SET v.gen = (v.gen + 1), parentId = @parentId
   FROM @viewGen AS v
   INNER JOIN sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities('dbo.' + @viewName, 'OBJECT') AS r ON r.referencing_entity_name = v.name

   UPDATE @viewGen
   SET gen = gen + 1
   WHERE Id = parentId OR parentId IN (SELECT Id FROM @viewGen WHERE parentId = parentId)

  END

 END
 SET @index = @index - 1
 IF (@index < 0) BEGIN SET @index = @cnt; END
END

SELECT gen as [order], name FROM @viewGen ORDER BY gen
```

Expecting result:

```
order   name
0       vw_Ancient  
1       vw_Child1   
1       vw_Child2   
2       vw_GrandChild
```